# Finding polynomials $g(x)$ such that $g(x)f(x)$ lies in an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

For a given multivariate polynomial ring over a field, take an ideal $I$ and a polynomial $f(x)$, where $x$ can represent several variables. I am interested in finding all polynomials $g(x)$ such that $g(x)f(x) \in I$. Clearly, this is satisfied if $g(x) \in I$. If there exist functions $k(x)$ such that $k(x) f(x) = 0$ we should (I think) be able to add these functions as additional generators in $I$ to create more valid possibilities. However, it is not obvious to me whether these possibilities are exhaustive, or if there are others. In principle, it seems like one can come up with polynomials that are specifically tailored to the form of $f(x)$ such that $g(x) f(x) \in I$ but $g(x) a(x) \notin I$ for a generic $a(x)$, and I'm not sure if just finding the $k(x)$ described above is sufficient to account for all these cases.

Comment: Is this a polynomial ring over a field, or over a more general ring?

Comment: Yes, a polynomial ring over a field. I have edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: In that case, are you familiar with this polynomial ring being a PID and having unique factorization?

Comment: I apologize, I should have clarified in my question that I'm interested in multivariate polynomials. I did not think this point would be relevant so I didn't include it, but now that you mention PIDs, it probably is.

Comment: These are exactly the elements of the [colon ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient) $(I: f)$. You should be able to compute a Gröbner basis for this ideal, which would then let you test membership using the division algorithm.